# Eclipse: how to format pointer declaration

Tags: c++, eclipse, coding-style

I know there are various schools of thought on how to format pointer variables, as:

```
char* array[4];
char * array[4];
char *array[4];
```

There's not one right way, but I'm comfortable with the first one.

By the way, copying and pasting code from other, I often find other formatting, and with autoformatting (ctrl+shift+f) this thing can't be fixed.

Is there a way to add an option in order to obtain this formatting?

I'm already searching on:

> window->preferences
>    C/C++->code style->formatter

But I can't find nothing usefull..

using Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that's something the current CDT formatter cannot do (see [Bug 287808](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=287808)). Although the status of the bug is assigned, so I hope it gets solved in the upcoming releases.
Bug description mentions, that Eclipse should try to preserve existing style, can't enforce one.

Answer (score 0):

My fairly old eclipse Version 10.5.0.202112050845 has this option:

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatter

Edit the profile

- Tab "White Space" -> Declarations -> Declarator List
- Tab "White Space" -> Declarations -> Functions

(both have to be edited, there seems to be no "global" rule)

Answer (score -1):

I just happened to read this document maybe it will be usefull , this is the n3242 standart for C++ which I believe is the most common nowadays. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf There is more "updated" standart such as n3249(I believe), but I think this is more usefull :)

Edit: Also if this will be helpful I am student of Computer Science and lectors write it as : "char* array[4]" and I do.(in case it matters to you :) )

Comment: thanks for link, but it don't solve my problem ): btw I was C.S. student too, and I have always heard "char* x" too!

Answer (score -1):

I found it more logical to format like this

```
int *p = nullptr;
```

Because in this case:

```
int *p, a, b;
```

It highlights, that not all 3 vars are declared as pointers, but only p.

While this:

```
int* p, a, b;
```

Is more likely to suggest, that all 3 are pointers to an integer.

Comment: There is also other logic why some people prefer to write int*: both int and * describe type of the variable, so, the types (int and pointer) are grouped and then the name goes after space.